# Remove size limit of WCF-Service answers

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created an WCF-Service that runs an operation on a W2008-Server and returns a datastructure as a result. Problem is, that this result can be larger, than the standard service configuration seems to accept. So I tried to increase (or remove) this maximum size, but it seems, I didn't found the correct properties.

In the App.config of the WCF, I changed the following values of my basicHttpBinding:

- MaxBufferPoolSize -> 6553600
- MaxBufferSize -> 6553600
- MaxReceiveMessageSize -> 6553600

ReaderQuotas:

- MaxArrayLenght -> 0
- MaxBytesPerRead -> 0
- MaxDepth -> 0
- MaxNameTableCharCount -> 0
- MaxStringContentLength -> 0

I then start the WCF-Testclient to call the service. I make sure, that the values for the properties of the basicHttpBinding are equal to the ones in the configuration. When I call the service in a way, that the result set is rather small, everything works fine. But when this size is increased, I eventually get the error (translated from german):

> Error while receiving http answer for http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/DiscoDataSource/Service1/. Possible reasons: Endpointbinding doesn't use the HTTP protocol or the HTTP-requestcontext was canceled by the server.
>
> Server stack trace:
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

I would like to configure the service to return the result regardless of the size. Anybody knows, where I need to change the configuration?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a large number of objects that are being serialized, WCF will hit a configured limit and barf. You've tried all the standard items, but there's one you left out: `maxItemsInObjectGraph`. Just like other config values, you'll need to set it both server-side *and* client-side. Here's a sample config snippit with an unnecessarily large value:

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
     <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
     </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
     <behavior name="ClientBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
     </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I'm obviously omitting a lot of tags in favor of illustrating where `maxItemsInObjectGraph` appears in your .config file.

Comment: Whoho! You hit the nail on the head, many thanks! It works now :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you changed those values on both the client and the server side as well?? You need to change them on both ends of the communication - only then it'll work.

If you haven't changed them on the server-side, the smaller value of both (client and server value) will "win".

Maybe, however, it's really just your **timeout settings** that cause the server to abort. On your binding, you can tweak the timeouts - by default, it's 60 seconds - so if grabbing the data and assembling it as needed takes more time, you'd need to adjust the `SendTimeout` on the binding, rather than the size settings.....

Comment: Yap, as I mentioned above, I made sure that the properties of the basicHttpBinding of the configuration of the WCF-Testclient are equal to the configuration of the app.config.
All timeouts are set to "10:00:00" (also on both sides)