# Send data to server from Windows Phone 7 to Web application using WCF . I am able to send few parameters but how can Ii send 10 ,15 or 20 rows of data

Tags: wcf, linq, windows-phone-7, windows-mobile

Send data to server from Windows Phone 7 to Web application using WCF . I am able to send few parameters but how can i send 10 ,15 or 20 rows of data.

I have saved the data in local database in the WP7 . I have a Task table there . There may be 10,15,20 or... rows of data in that table . I want to send those number of rows of data to server using my wcf service . I am able to send the parameter to the server like i have a login method in the wcf which takes email and password as parameter returns boolean value true or false. Now I need to send these few 10,15,20 or... rows of data to the server via the WCF service and save in the server database. I am stuck at sending the number of rows to the wcf method. I have the Task data in list object. I have debugged and checked the presence of data.

Here is the code part

```
using (dbContext context = new dbContext())
{                  
     IQueryable<tasks> taskStatQuery = from t in context.Tasks  select t;
     List<tasks> allTasksStatus = taskStatQuery.ToList();

     WcfFSMSer.Win7MobileServiceClient client = new WcfFSMSer.Win7MobileServiceClient();

     client.TestFunctionAsync(whatParamToSendForSendingFewRows);
     client.TestFunctionCompleted += new EventHandler<WcfFSMSer.TestFunctionCompletedEventArgs>(client_TestFunctionCompleted);

}

void client_TestFunctionCompleted(object sender, WcfFSMSer.TestFunctionCompletedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

I am able to get all tasks list in this variable  List allTasksStatus.
When i add parameter it gives red underline and says best overload have some invalid argument. ie the task class in the List is unknown to wcf. I also tried writing the same class in the WCF but still no use. If i try to send any collection object to the method through parameter it still gives me error. Tried to send array also to no use.

How to send these values from WP7 to WCF?

***Does any one have any link or example , to send atleast 2,3 rows of data ?***

Please let me know if any other more information is needed to solve this issue

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try and increase the maxBufferSize & maxReceivedMessageSize for WCF service. Similar kind of question is here: [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightnet/thread/03603b20-8343-4ea6-80da-90a7cd3763bb/) or [StackOverflow forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874499/remove-size-limit-of-wcf-service-answers)

Comment: In What type of object i should send this data . datatable or dataset is not available in WP7. I am having data in List but how to send this to WCF. I am unable to send even 2, 3 rows of data.

Comment: Do u have any link or example to send at least 2,3 rows of data

Comment: Try 3rd answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288883/how-to-pass-listobject-to-wcf

Answer (score 0):

This is not good way to call method a lot of time.

The better way to do this i make other method in WCF who take list of task. Like this:

```
   public bool TestFunction(List<Task> list)
    {
      foreach(var task in list)
      {
         //put to the database
      }
    }
```

And now you can send your list of task by WCF client:

```
client.TestFunction(taskList);
```

Here you can read more about data types: [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx)

Comment: How the method in the WCF know about the Task class. Even if we make a same Task class in wcf will it work ?

Comment: When i add parameter it gives red underline and says best overload have some invalid argument. ie the task class in the List is unknown to wcf. I also tried writing the same class in the WCF but still no use